# Is it possible to make minor (making a space between two words) proof corrections after already submitting a proof reading to a journal?

Tags: publications

After submitting back an online proof reading corrections of an accepted paper, I found a very trivial mistake; just making space between two words. The words take vague meaning if left not spaced. Is that possible to make one more proof read to correct this typo error?

Comment: Just write an email to the production office. A lacking space seems to be just a typo, there should be absolutely no problems to correct it given the paper has not yet reached a point in which it is impossible to make corrections.

Comment: Does "an online proof reading corrections of an accepted paper" mean "camera-ready version"? If so, then you need to act _immediately_, since the publisher may be near ready to release on an online version, and I wouldn't expect the publisher to permit changes at this stage. (Camera-ready is final.)

Comment: Thanks all. But I noticed the error after the article was released online (published).

Comment: You can try to correct it by contacting the journal. they are the only ones who can decide if they want to change it. On the other hand: nobody cares about the extra space (like it or not). We are interested in the science.

Comment: Thank you Louic. I'll try to contact the journal but I'm afraid if they release the article as "Erratum" or "Corrigendum" because of this very minor mistake. To explain the problem it is like "late aged adult" and the error happened when I write it as "Lateaged adults". Mind the space between "late" and "Aged". This error happened in 9 places in the paper. That was the problem that I notice after the paper was published.

Comment: The journals I'm familiar with reserve errata for significant errors, which this is not. They may say "oh well, this is how it is now", or make a slight adjustment given how recently it was published.

Answer (score 2):

Email the production editor as soon as possible that you've found this extra correction. If it's still not inconvenient for them, they'll probably fix it. However, because it's such a minor error, you should be ready for them to say "it's too late" as well. This probably won't lead to an errata or corrigendum - it's just too minor.

If your previous reading had contained lots and lots of corrections, it's possible they're already planning to send you a set of second proofs.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanations and important ideas. Unfortunately the paper was published online two days ago, and I identified this very minor error after one day of the publication. This "lageaged" consistently occurred in many places that increased my worry. After looking at most of your suggestions, I emailed the production team to ask about this and now waiting for their response.

Comment: If it's already been published online, chances are it's too late.